# Using Python and BeautifulSoup, is there a way to find "strong" tag within only specific part of a page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

so I'm trying to find on a web site, all texts with "strong" tag, but within only specific part of the page as opposed to finding all texts with "strong tag".
This is the code I have so far.

```
for link in soup.find_all("strong"):
    file = open('destination', 'a')
    sys.stdout = file
    print(link.text)
```

Comment: Can you share URL or HTML code so we can see where the `<strong>` tag is located and how to target it?

Comment: Are you targeting always `<strong>` element that goes after `Grade:`?

Comment: So I'm targeting <strong> element that goes before and after Grade: until it gets to that list.

Comment: See my answer, maybe it's that what you're searching for

Answer (score 0):

First find anything that you do not "like" and then Use [Going up](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-up), Going sideways, Going back and forth etc.

Answer (score 0):

`beautifulsoup4==4.7.1` version needed:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.cbssports.com/wwe/news/wwe-smackdown-results-recap-grades-kevin-owens-steals-the-show-ahead-of-extreme-rules/'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

for strong in soup.select('#article-main-body strong:not(#article-main-body h3:last-of-type ~* strong)'):
    print(strong.text)
```

Prints:

```
Big fan of WWE? 
Subscribe to our podcast -- State of Combat with Brian Campbell
 -- where we go in depth on everything you need to know in WWE each week.
Roman Reigns def. Dolph Zigger via pinfall: 
Grade:
B+
```

Comment: I would need to get basically find all <strong> elements up on til that header in the middle of the page.

Comment: @JohnDavis This searches every `<strong>` in the article until that `<h3>` element